# Authenticate and Show an Azure AD secured Web App View from an Third Party App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

**Background**
I have a `MVC 5` Web App and hosted in `Azure App Service` as Web App and secured with `Azure AD`; Anybody with valid AD credentials can authenticate themselves and view all HTML Content in the Web App;

**Objective**
I need to give just one of these MVC-View to outside individuals to view. For such we have already created an User in `Azure AD` which we will be sharing the details with the outside world. Hence, the thrid party will need to write some code to authenticate to our Azure AD and view this HTML content non interactively (Which means without allowing the third party app to prompt to enter user credentials from Azure AD).

**What I have thought about**

> Assume that I am the third Party, I am going to authenticate to Azure AD from a Console/WinForms/HTML
>   Page and get myself a token; Then I will be using the token, to open
>   up a Browser to view this page.

**Challenges I see**
Session Expiration
Session Validity

**Putting everything intto a Picture**
[image]

Please show me some guidence to accomplish the objective.

Comment: Hey, can you add a diagram that explains the scenario? It would be helpful.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni Diagram enclosed! :)

Comment: How did you implement the authentication / authorization part? [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) without changing your code or  use the [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/) middleware for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hence, the thrid party will need to write some code to authenticate to our Azure AD and view this HTML content **non interactively** (Which means without allowing the third party app to prompt to enter user credentials from Azure AD).

Per my understanding, you could leverage the [OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) by using the `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Also, you could use [OAuth 2 Resource Owner Password Credentials grant](https://github.com/nordvall/TokenClient/wiki/OAuth-2-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-grant-in-AzureAd). **Note:** The resource owner password grant doesn't provide consent and doesn't support MFA either. Detailed tutorial, you could follow [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/).

Based on the authentication implementation part in your Web App, you could follow the approaches below to implement your scenario:

- For using [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview)

  You do not need to modify any code in your Web App project.
- For using [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/) middleware

  You could use [Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory/) package in your Web App for supporting AAD bearer token authentication, and this middleware need to be configured before the other authentication middlewares as follows:

```html
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Audience = "{the-AAD-clientId}",
            Tenant = "{TenantId}"
        });
  
//app.UseCookieAuthentication
//app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication
```

For the client (the third Party), they could leverage the above two flows (Client Credentials Grant Flow ,Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow) to retrieve the access token without user interaction. Then they could access the specific view page by using the token as follows:

```html
Get https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/home/index
Header Authorization:Bearer {the-AAD-accessToken-or-IdToken}
```

For retrieving the token, you could follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/blob/master/TodoListClient/Program.cs) for using User Password Credential flow. For Client Credential, you could just construct the `ClientCredential` instance when invoking `AcquireTokenAsync` for getting the token.

Additionally, you could create a new AAD application for this scenario or just use the AAD application for your current Web App. Moreover, there may exists risks when exposing the username & password or clientId & ClientSecret to the third Party, I would recommend you expose a new endpoint for generating the token in your Web App backend and return the token to the third party for security consideration.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail answer. Let me go through and understand those.

Comment: Thank You for your detail explanation. I actually was able to get the token. BTW, should i give graphapi's [URL](https://graph.windows.net) as resource when calling `AcquireTokenAsync` ?

Comment: If you want to use the token to access the AD Graph API, you need to set the resource parameter to `https://graph.windows.net/` and set the related required permissions for your AAD app on Azure portal.