# Authenticate and Show an Azure AD secured Web App View from an Third Party App: Part 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal

**Overview**
I am arriving at this post from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928875/authenticate-and-show-an-azure-ad-secured-web-app-view-from-an-third-party-app). After reviewing the links, I understood that I had to register my third party application in Azure AD as a `Native Application`. So both of the applications are registered in Azure AD.

I have created my app under the [Daemon or Server Application to Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) Application Type and Scenario.

**Problem**
After going through Bruce Chen's provided resource links, I was able to build my code to receive a token; and Indeed I got a token. However when I access the Resource I was intended to show, I am seeing the Username and Password Prompt is thrown.

**My Workround**

```
    string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
                string tenant = "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
                string clientId = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
                string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

                string todoListResourceId = @"https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Customer/CashSummary?term=673130569-VN/00";
                string todoListBaseAddress = @"https://graph.windows.net";
                AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
                AuthenticationResult result = null;

                authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new FileCache());
                UserCredential uc = new UserPasswordCredential("xxxx@jkintranet.com", "xxxxxxxx");

                try
                {
// I am getting the Token here.                    
result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListBaseAddress, clientId, uc).Result;

                    #region Call Web APP
    //Here with the Token I am calling the MVC Web Resource View
                    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(todoListResourceId).Result;


                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
// I am getting the response content as the Microsoft Identity Provider's User name and password Prompt instead of my MVC-View's HTML Content                        
string rezstring = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        var todoArray = JArray.Parse(rezstring);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        foreach (var todo in todoArray)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(todo["Title"]);
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
                    return;
                }
```

[The Resource](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless)

**My Concerns**

`Resource` in `AcquireTokenAsync`; What is the `Resource` here, Is it Graph API's URI or APP ID's URI or anything else?

I had used Graph API's URI and was able to successfully get a token.

**Appreciation**
[@Bruce-Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6755924/bruce-chen) for a guided explanation.

Comment: How to Find your [App ID URI](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/4108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource should be the *allowed audience* for the API.

That should be the Application Id URI of your API, or the client id of the API.

If you specify `https://graph.windows.net` as the resource URI, you get an access token which can call the Azure AD Graph API, but not your API.

Comment: Ok after using `App ID URI` I am getting a token, but when I use it to make a HTTP request with the token I got I am getting the Page which prompts for _Sign in to your account_ page instead of the page result I am intended to get. Whats wrong?

Comment: Ahh. That's something I should have mentioned too. The fact that the API is redirecting you to login is not right. That means it is setup to use OpenID Connect, not OAuth. You are going to have to configure the app to accept OAuth Bearer tokens.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Can you point out to any resources on how can I configure my application to accept OAuth Bearer tokens?

Comment: What are you running on? Azure Web App? What framework and language are you using?

Comment: My _Service app_ is as an Azure Web App with .Net framework 4.5 and `C#`; The _client app_ can be console or web, but for testing I am just running it on a C# WinForms Application.

Comment: Alright, this sample might help you: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs. The link is to the authentication configuration for the API they have in the sample.